# Program using scanf in a loop prints incorrect output

Tags: c

I don't know what's happening with this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
   {
   int ii[5], i;
   for (i=1; i<=5; i++)
   {
      scanf("%d", &ii[i]);
   }
   printf("----------------------\n");  
   for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
   printf("%d\n", ii[i]);
   return 0;
   }
```

After compiling when I provide input as

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

then it prints as it is,
but when I provide input in reverse order:

```
5 4 3 2 1
```

it keeps on asking up to some more digits and after that it prints out some random digits from given set of input.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `ii[i]` for `i=5` is UB.

Comment: `for (i=1; i<=5; i++)` -- must be 0..4 not 1..5

Comment: These random digits are actually undefined behavior, and you're lucky you're only getting them.

Note that arrays are zero based, the indexes run from 0 to N-1 and not from 1 to N.

Comment: If the input is literally `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, the `scanf` is never going to get past the first comma. You should always check the value returned by `scanf`. (Read the man page or other documentation to find out what that value means.)

Comment: @KeithThompson no its not "," i have just described so that it can be more readable

Comment: @MarounMaroun you are right Maroun . but i have also tried other programs by using indexes from 0 to N and they worked too, but dont know whats the problem with this code

Comment: @user1576448 The problem was clearly explained to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

c uses `0 indexing` that means that array indexes start at 0 not 1. A for loop over an array should look like this:

```
int array[ARRAY_LENGTH], i;
for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; ++i) {
```

This will ensure that `i` will go from `0` to `ARRAY_LENGTH - 1` and will not go outside the bounds of your array.

These lines:

```
for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
printf("%d\n", ii[i]);
```

will Access element `5` of `ii` where the maximum index is 4. This will cause *Undefined Behavior* which is likely why you are seeing random numbers appear.